# Download vscode extension via api and correct target version

Tags: visual-studio-code

I try to download vscode extensions using curl as per this [documentation](https://vscode-docs1.readthedocs.io/en/latest/editor/extension-gallery/#common-questions). While this works for most extensions, I did not find out how to download a specific target architecture version such as linux-64 for the cpptools extension.

There is a solution to use the following url

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/_apis/public/gallery/publishers/ms-vscode/vsextensions/cpptools/1.18.0/vspackage?targetPlatform=linux-64
```

Problem with this endpoint is that it fails quite often due to `RequestBlockedException`. This is not very reliable and I was wondering if it could be done via `ms-python.gallery.vsassets.io/` API